# Update records with new objects

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, mongomock

Say I have the following MongoDB collection (am using `mongomock` for this example so it's easy to reproduce):

```
import mongomock

collection = mongomock.MongoClient().db.collection

objects = [{'name': 'Alice', 'age': 21}, {'name': 'Bob', 'age': 20}]
collection.insert_many(objects)
```

I then would like to update my existing objects with the fields from some new objects:

```
new_objects = [{'name': 'Alice', 'height': 170}, {'name': 'Caroline', 'height': 160}]
```

The only way I could think of doing this is:

```
for record in new_objects:
    if collection.find_one({'name': record['name']}) is not None:
        collection.update_one({'name': record['name']}, {'$set': {'height': record['height']}})
    else:
        collection.insert_one(record)
```

However, if `new_objects` is very large, then this method becomes slow - is there a way to use `update_many` for this?

Comment: Couldn't you just append to a list all the objects that you want to update and then loop through and update them?

Comment: Thanks @unltd_J but I don't understand, could you show an example please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `update_many()`, because it requires a single filter which in your use case would not work as each filter is different.

A simpler construct uses `upsert=True` to avoid the insert/update logic, and also sets all the fields specified in the record which is less coding :

```
for record in objects + new_objects:
    collection.update_one({'name': record.get('name')}, {'$set': record}, upsert=True)
```

If it is slowing down with a larger number of updates, make sure you have an index on the `name` field using (in mongo shell):

```
db.collection.createIndex( { "name": 1 } )
```

You can squeeze a bit more performance out by using a bulk_write operation. Worked example:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient, UpdateOne

collection = MongoClient().db.collection

objects = [{'name': 'Alice', 'age': 21}, {'name': 'Bob', 'age': 20}]
new_objects = [{'name': 'Alice', 'height': 170}, {'name': 'Caroline', 'height': 160}]

updates = []

for record in objects + new_objects:
    updates.append(UpdateOne({'name': record.get('name')}, {'$set': record}, upsert=True))

collection.bulk_write(updates)

for record in collection.find({}, {'_id': 0}):
    print(record)
```

Gives:

```
{'name': 'Alice', 'age': 21, 'height': 170}
{'name': 'Bob', 'age': 20}
{'name': 'Caroline', 'height': 160}
```